# Loading an external xml file and then saving it into a website directory using PHP

Tags: php, xml

So I found this page: [Load external XML and save it using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13829364/load-external-xml-and-save-it-using-php) to help me out, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

I'm trying to do the same thing by loading an external xml file and saving it (with no changes to the xml file) into my website directories as a batch system. I have already dynamically created all the directories needed.
ex:

```
/xml/en/281
```

Now what I'm trying to do is load the company's xml files (https://thiscompany.com/xml/en/281/18511095_en.xml) and save it in my own directory as the same name, 18511095_en.xml in the 281 directory.

I've been researching and I am getting lots of simplexml_load_file and DOMDocument examples but I'm not getting the results I needed.

For all sake and purposes here is the code: (I'm changing the url of the actual xml file because my client doesn't want it out there.
**EDITED from the responses below**

```
$url = "https://thiscompany.com/xml/en/281/18511095_en.xml";
$timeout = 10;

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
file_put_contents(__DIR__ . "/xml/18511095_en.xml", $response);
```

I'm assuming the problem is with the saveXML path. The xml directory is at the root of my website. Do I need to include, http://www.....com? 
xml, en, and 281 all have 0777 permissions.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have the XML file in memory. Why are you putting it into an XML parser and then turning it back into XML without modification? Just save the file you have.

Comment: @Quentin, "thiscompany.com" is the whole company, the site I'm working on has it's own domain for this company.

Comment: That doesn't appear to have anything to do with my comment.

Comment: So you're saying I can just take the xml file and save it directly into my domain without xml parsing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the path on your *filesystem*, not a URL.

e.g. `"/var/www/www.example.com/htdocs/xml/en/281/18511095_en.xml"`

Comment: So looking at my file path in filezilla.... /public_html/stage/cat/xml/en/281. Is that the correct path then?

Comment: It's rare to see a public_html directory in the root of a server's file system. Your FTP account is probably chrooted, in which case, no, that isn't right.

Comment: Oops. Here is the actual path after using __DIR__. /home/USERNAME/public_html/stage/cat

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way to copy a remote file into the same directory as your PHP file:

```
$url = "http://www.test.com/xmlfile.xml";
$contents = file_get_contents($url);
file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . "/xmlfile.xml", $contents);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also accomplish this without having to use simplexml_load_string which will use more memory on your server. Instead try the following:

```
$xml = file_get_contents("https://thiscompany.com/xml/en/281/18511095_en.xml");
file_put_contents("/var/www/my/full/data/path/filename.xml", $xml);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
$xml->saveXML("/xml/en/281/18511095_en.xml");
```

First of all, you should use a relative path instead of an absolute one. In this example you are trying to save the file under the `/xml` folder on the root filesystem and there's most likely no such directory and you don't have permissions to write to that directory (assuming it exists). Use a relative path.

Secondly, you don't need to parse the `XML` file, you can save it directly. Here's a working example:

```
$response = curl_exec($curl);
file_put_contents(__DIR__ . "/xml/en/281/xmlfile.xml", $response);
```

Further reading: [Absloute path vs relative path in Linux/Unix](http://www.linuxnix.com/2012/07/abslute-path-vs-relative-path-in-linuxunix.html)

Comment: Thanks! I tested the second piece of code, and it works, but saves it into the root of my site. I would like to save it in (after the DIR__/xml/en/281. I have xml, en, and 281 all set up with 0777 permissions, but it won't save it.

Comment: Edited question to reflect your case. Check if the syntax is the same. You can also try to assemble the path in a variable and echo it and check its contents. Also, what error do you get?